# Clear the output buffer in telnetlib on Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, send, telnet, telnetlib

I want to establish one telnet connection but I don't want to see in the terminal what I write and read.
e.g.

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
tn.write(command.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
time.sleep(0.1)
ret = True if b'iconstorage' in self.tn.read_until(b'iconstorage') else False
.
.
.
```

I don't want to see anything but still receive

```
    Telnet(host): send b'command\n'
    Telnet(host): recv b'\xff\xfd\x01\xff\xfd\x1f\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03\r\r\nls\r\n~ # ls\r\n\x1b[1;34mbin\x1b[0m         '
    Telnet(host): IAC DO 1
    Telnet(host): IAC DO 31
    Telnet(host): IAC WILL 1
    Telnet(host): IAC WILL 3

.
.
.
```

Is it possible to avoid that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only be seeing things like that if you've enabled debug mode on that instance of the `Telnet` class.

Debug mode is off by default, so unless you've changed `telnetlib.py`, there's no way you can get that output with the code block you posted in the question.

Either way, you can explicitly disable it with...

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet()
tn.set_debug_level(0)
tn.open(host)
tn.write(command.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
# etc.
```

Comment: Hmm.. I think you are right.
I will try it out first think in the morning.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cooli, If you like this answer and helped you, please consider checking it as the right answer, that's SO's etiquette :)